# Error while compiling swagger-codegen java Petstore sdk

Tags: java, gson, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate a java API using swagger-codegen (3.0.0)
I am using the swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.24.jar version of codegen jar.
I ran the following command to generate the SDK for the sample petstore project:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i code/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/3_0_0/petstore.json -l java -o out/pet-java
```

When I am compiling the generated sdk project:

```
cd out/pet-java
mvn clean package
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] out/pet-java/src/main/java/io/swagger/client/model/Pet.java:[87,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method nextObject()
[ERROR]   location: variable jsonReader of type com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
```

```
it is using <gson-version>2.8.1</gson-version> as dependency.
```

Comment: The codegen seems to be broken. There is not `nextObject` in [JsonReader](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html).

Comment: did you also face the same problem?

Comment: I don't use Swagger 3, still on Swagger 2 (+codegen), I'm only telling that the code generated by the codegen cannot be compiled because the codegen generates illegal code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error generating java code from swagger based on the Strava API:
https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json.  For their API, they use swagger 2.x.

Comment: Fixing my comment above, I get the same error when compiling the generated java: there is no method nextObject() in JsonReader.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your inputs, did you find any workaround or solution to fix this?
I also configured my machine to use JDK 8, but the problem persists.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.  I added similar comments to a couple of issues, including yours, on the swagger-codegen github page.  There were 2500 issues already so I'm not sure how likely a quick fix will be.

Comment: All of the offending code is in these nested static Adapter classes derived from TypeAdapter.  I'm trying to figure out what the code is trying to do and if there's a way to do it with existing calls to the JsonReader.  This is a hobby project for me so I'm not spending a lot of time on it.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in 3.0.25
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/commit/8f23a89ce4c75597b8deb82e010fa1e8037168d8

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately the real answer is for swagger-codegen to fix their regression.  They've admitted that it's a problem.  In the mean time I've worked around the issue for my particular situation.  To demonstrate the types of changes that are necessary, see below:

[image]

In some files instead of nextObject(), there may be a call to next().  The solution is the same, however.

Apologies for any confusion in the diff.  Apparently I left the original lines in the file commented out below the working replacement line.

Comment: In the code that was auto generated for me, out of 91 files, 10 needed the fix above for 'nextObject()' or 'next()'.